# faceted search gives number greater than 1 for 1 result

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I have query from my to solr looking like this

```
q=(rtitle:(work+codex))&facet=true&facet.field=record_type&facet.field=subject0&facet.field=grid&facet.limit=9000&start=0&rows=0
```

Not the funny thing that many of my records can be found by using word "work" and word "codex". And when I do query like the above one I get something like that

`<lst name="grid"><int name="23908">2</int></lst>`

The value in `name` is the some kind of id of my record. In my db I got only **one** record with the id = 23908 so I was sure that faceted will return mi number 1 but it looks like it gives me 2 cause that record can be found for each of this words.

When I do query like this:

```
q=(rtitle:(work+AND+codex))&facet=true&facet.field=record_type&facet.field=subject0&facet.field=grid&facet.limit=9000&start=0&rows=0
```

I get correct faceted BUT the query isn't what I want to get. Id doesn not return results with the quality that I need so it is wrong for me.

What can I do to have OR between words and get faceted search to count my results correct as uniq values not sum of them ?

---

**UPDATE**

Ok I fond the bug in my code. As I can see one of developers in the data-config set uid of diffrent record type to that field (I have two data configs). In some cases id from one data type and from the second where the same for one phrase. That way I got number of 2 not 1